# iOS signing information about phonegap

Tags: ios, cordova, certificate, provisioning-profile

I've read that to build an IOS app with phonegap i need certificate and provisioning profile.
For my personal test I configure my certificate with UDIDs of the Apple devices to test it on them , but if want to publish this app for all Apple devices ?
What should I do?
For now I only create an apk file and  install it on every android devices...

Comment: Are you wanting to publish on the app store or are you doing an internal distribution, which develop license do you have?

Comment: Internal distribution for this time...in future i wanna publish on the store...
I don t have the license now,but i will buy next days...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You will need to create and sign your app with a Distribution Provisioning , that its not limiting to only test devices.

[image: Distribution Provisioning]